# foreach a list of class constructors in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, collections

I'm pretty new to kotlin and I've been reading through the language docs to start picking it up.

I learn much better when I type out the examples, so I wanted to make a little example running codebase so I could follow along with the examples.

This is fine for writing each of examples in the main.kt file on it's own, running it, then blowing it away, but I'd like to create an example class for each section, create a list of the classes in main, and then foreach over them.

I created an interface which has a declaration for a common member function for running the examples:

```
interface ExampleCodeInterface {

    /**
     * Run the examples for the current Example class
     */
    fun runExamples()
}
```

And defined an example class:

```
class CollectionExamples : ExampleCodeInterface{

    fun listExample() {
        val systemUsers: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf(1,2,3)
        val sudoers: List<Int> = systemUsers

        fun addSudoer(newUser: Int) {
            systemUsers.add(newUser)
        }

        fun getSysSudoers(): List<Int> {
            return sudoers
        }

        addSudoer(4)
        println("Total sudoers: ${getSysSudoers().size}")
        getSysSudoers().forEach {
            i -> println("Some useful info on user $i")
        }
    }

    override fun runExamples() {
        listExample()
    }
}
```

The thing I'm not sure on is how to properly run this from main.kt

I know the class works because when I create a new instance and fire the method it works, but I can't quite figure out how to properly create a list of class constructors so that I can have a list of classes that all extend the `ExampleCodeInterface` that I can forEach through and fire the method:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val exampleClassList: List<ExampleCodeInterface> = listOf<ExampleCodeInterface>(CollectionExamples)

    exampleClassList.forEach {
        val exampleSet = it()
        exampleSet.runExamples()
    }

//    val collectionExamples = CollectionExamples()
//    collectionExamples.runExamples()
}
```

[image: non-working code]

I've been trying to piece together the logic from the docs, but I think there are some details that I don't know yet.

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: why not create objects in a list `listOf(CollectionExamples())` or do you need a list of factory functions?

Comment: OH! YEAH THAT TOTALLY WORKED!! If you add an answer I'll throw you the check. Thanks!!

Comment: If you do want a list of constructors, you can use function references, like ``val constructors = listOf(::Class1, ::Class2)``, and instantiate them with something like ``constructors.forEach { it() }`` (or ``it.invoke()`` if you like that better)

Comment: Ah @cactustictacs yeah this is what I was originally trying to do. knowing that `::` snytax is def super helpful.